# L0 and L1 Minimization of Matrix Equation

Tags: optimization, extreme-value

I am aiming to solve a 'raw' L0/L1-Minimisation problem, i.e, trying to find 
$$\min_{\alpha=0,1} \|x\|_{\alpha} : Ax=b $$
where $A,b$ are complex-valued matrices.

In particular, I've been trying to find a software package (preferably in Python, Julia or C though I'm also open to Matlab) that would help me solve this.

Most code for these $L_\alpha$ minimisation problems seems to come from the machine learning community, and in particular seems to focus on either the L1-approximation problem ($\min \|Ax-b\|_{1}$), or the [L1-regularized least-squares problem](http://cvxopt.org/examples/mlbook/l1regls.html).

I'm new to this kind of optimisation problem, so I'd like to ask the community:

- Is there a way to translate my problem to fit one of these software implementations?
- Do people know a software package to solve this 'bare' problem?
- Would an algorithm to solve my optimisation problem be relatively simple to implement myself?

Comment: Are you saying $\alpha$ takes on only two values, $0,1$ or perhaps $\alpha\in[0,1]$? Also, what are the details about $A,b$? Is the system solvable uniquely or does $A$ have a non-trivial kernel?

Comment: Sorry, yes, $\alpha$ is strictly 0 or 1. I'll have to check more thoroughly about A but I think it has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Could you define the 0-norm? Is it just the geometric mean of absolute values of $x$?

Comment: I'm defining the 0-norm as the number of non-zero elements in the vector, and the 1 norm as the sum of absolute values of the elements

Comment: The [Smoothed-L0 algorithm](http://ee.sharif.edu/~SLzero/) seems to work well for the $\|x\|_{0}$ case, an is fairly simple to implement in python (the rest of my codebase for this project is python). Still looking for a nice method for the $\|x\|_{1}$ case though!